# sql view returns different results with join

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, join, view

Ive faced strange problem. I have a grid feed by entity framework, grid results are taken from sql view. Its code first, view's entity is mapped to actual sql view:

```
public class MyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyViewEntity>
{
    public MyMap()
    {
        ToTable("vw_MyView");
        HasKey(v => v.OrderID);
    }
}
```

My view in sql have joins, this is simplified query produced by EF, commented out fields come from joins:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[a] AS [a], 
    [Extent1].[b] AS [b], 
    [Extent1].[c] AS [c], 
    --[Extent1].[SenderCountry] AS [SenderCountry], 
    --[Extent1].[SenderCode] AS [SenderCode], 
    [Extent1].[d] AS [d], 
    [Extent1].[e] AS [e], 
    [Extent1].[f] AS [f], 
    --[Extent1].[Occasion] AS [Occasion], 
    [Extent1].[g] AS [g], 
    [Extent1].[h] AS [h]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_MyView] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Receiver] = xxx
    order by extent1.[date] DESC
    OFFSET 40 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

this code produces such results (a field)

```
119900
119934
119943
119948
119949
119968
120004
120020
120030
120057
```

Now lets put senderCode field again to our query. SenderCode comes from table Member which is joined to our main table (this from which a b c d.. fields come from) on Member.ID = mainTable.c, results are:

```
120117
119943
119934
119948
119949
120120
120121
120122
120030
120057
```

119900 disappears from result, 120117 jumps into its place. All output records have d field which for every record has value 2, except record 119900 which has 3.
In second result all records have 2 in field d. Field d is not used in any join or where clause.
Can anybody tell me what happens here? Why join behaves so diffrent when selecting field from joined table?  It will produce difference for every offset.

Thanks!

Comment: Do all of those IDs have the same date? If so both are correct results. You need a unique order by to ensure deterministic results.

Comment: 119900 and 120117 (these switched) have both the same date, but different from the rest. Do you mean its impossible to order by by date as its not unique? If so, how to resolve sorting in grid?

Comment: I don't know this grid. Is it customisable so you can always append a a unique secondary column to act as a tiebreaker to ensure stable results?

Comment: In fact it is, its grid.mvc so ti can be modfied easily. Getting back to sql query, do you mean order by extent.date, extent.PK desc? It ruins the idea of having records sorted descending by date..

Comment: Yes I do mean that and no it doesn't as the PK only enters into it for rows which have the same date and orders them consistently within that date. The result is still ordered by date in the same way as a phone book is still ordered by surname even though people with the same surname are ordered by first name.

Comment: Ok, I didnt add sort direction to second order by. Maaaan, I would get you a beer :) Many thanks!